# How I can shortly prove that you can have a closed knight's tour on the 6x6 chessboard?

Tags: hamiltonian-path, chessboard, knight-tours

On the [website](http://gaebler.us/share/Knight_tour.html), the explanation that a knight's tour on a $6\times6$ board is possible is the continued proof of around $1\frac{1}{2}$ pages! It will be great if one of you could provide a simple, concise proof that the $6\times6$ is possible.

After being asked this question I tried to formulate conjectures to try and prove that the 6x6 is possible by finding solutions based on rules that I thought might work, such as:

[image: My unsatisfactory previous answer]

However, I still couldn't implement this otherwise-logical 'theorem' in the 6x6 -- I kept running into problems!
Even when I *did* get it, the vague explanation is just unsatisfactory, and I couldn't really define my method.
I still can't find a way to prove that it really *is* possible without just giving a straight-up solution.

Comment: Choose a better title- one that relates to the question.

Comment: Please review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Comment: @Laufen, I will now. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: The existence of a closed knight's tour on a $6\times6$ chessboard can be established with a single example of such a tour. If that's all you want to prove, why bother with the confusing diagrams at all?

Comment: @Barry --- I get your point!

Comment: But I think the meaning of the dotted lines is that they signify an unspecified path that visits all the rest of the squares in their respective grids other than the ones with circles in them. So the idea seems to be that if you juxtapose a closed tour next to an open tour that starts and stops at the indicated black circles, you can rejoin things to get a closed tour on the combined grid.

Comment: @Barry, I am aware of that now :-)

Comment: I explained that diagram in my answer to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4018743/362967). Why do you ask about it again here? (Or was that not your edit?) As for the 6x6 closed tour, the page you link to shows a picture of one. It is used as a base case for proving the existence of closed tours on larger boards.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: Check the edit history; the **NOTE** part is NOT written by the OP, but someone else who edited the question. I tried to reject the edit but failed.

Comment: Exhibiting a solution is a proof. And at the link, that is indeed all they do to verify that a $6\times 6$ board has a closed knights tour.

Comment: @Joffan, you do have a valid point!